# JBoss 6 creates instance of web service on startup

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, jboss, jboss6.x

I'm migrating my ear application from JBoss 5 to 6.0.0.Final. I noticed that JBoss 6.0.0.Final instantiates beans which have @WebService annotation on startup. JBoss 5 didn't do that. Is it possible to disable this behaviour in JBoss 6?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy directly contains all the modules that get started up.
What I usually do, is I first backup that deploy directly, and then start stripping out components and check to see if jboss still properly starts and does what I need it to do.
I then use 'netstat' (command line util, which I believe is also on Windows in the dos prompt), to check for any unexpected ports it might be listening on.

Crude. Not good enough to expose to the internet, but ok for intranet use.
Exposing to the internet is another kettle of fish. I'd use a scalable reverse proxy for that, but that's a whole other story.

Also check out JBoss 7. They're boasting about how "fast" it now is. Perhaps inspired by Glassfish which starts pretty much instantaneously...?